# JList horizontal resize causes vertical shrink

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I have a jList in a ScrollPane and it behaves weird when I am resizing my frame. 
Normally it is like this:
[image: Before]
And after I grow the table on the left horizontally, my jList becomes like this:
[image: After]

I am posting some code of the gui which might be helpful:

```
    scrlInterfaceList.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrlInterfaceList.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    //---- list1 ----
    lstInterfaces.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(LFwPolicyMaker.messages.getString("IpMacMatcher.MatchTab.controlPanel.interfaces.title")));
    lstInterfaces.setPreferredSize(null);
    lstInterfaces.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(55, 90));
    lstInterfaces.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(55, 90));

    lstInterfaces.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    lstInterfaces.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {

        String[] strings = getInterfaces();

        public int getSize() {
            return strings.length;
        }

        public Object getElementAt(int i) {
            return strings[i];
        }
    });
    scrlInterfaceList.setViewportView(lstInterfaces);

    setSelectedInterfaces();

    add(scrlInterfaceList,new GridBagConstraints(0, 5, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
```

What might be the problem? I want the jList to continue shrinking horizontally, like the combobox, buttons above

Comment: *"I am posting some code of the gui which might be helpful:"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Try setting the weighty value of the GridBagConstraints to 1.0 for the scrollpane

Comment: @MadProgrammer that worked thanks. Maybe you should add it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Alptugay ask and you shell receive ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the weighty value of the GridBagConstraints to 1.0 for the scrollpane